# Rule about function parameter and default-initialization

Tags: c++

```
int foo(int arg1, int arg2 = arg1)
{
    std::cout << arg2;
}
```

Why the c++ standard does not allow this king of default parameter initialization ?

Comment: Because you can get the same thing with overloading? I mean, `int foo(int arg1) { foo(arg1, arg1); }`.

Comment: @raina77ow well you can use overloading to get the same thing for `int foo(int arg1, int arg2=0){}` as `int foo(int arg1){ return foo(arg1,0); }` so that doesn't really answer the question as why it allows one and not the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unusually, this is one case where the standard does give a justification (although not a particularly compelling one):

> C++11 8.3.6/9 The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in a default argument, even if they are not evaluated.

It's not a particularly arduous restriction, since you can achieve the same effect with an overload:

```
int foo(arg1) {return foo(arg1, arg1);}
```